# Is there a TypeScript compiler option to disallow `let x;` (no type annotation, no initializer)?

Tags: typescript, configuration

Without adding a linter, I want to disallow using `let x;` without any type annotation or initializer. If it has an initializer, that's fine, TypeScript will infer the type from the initializer. But without one, `x` has the type `any` — even with `noImplicitAny` set, which surprised me.

So:

```typescript
// This is fine, type is inferred from initializer:
let a = 42;

// Also fine, type is provided explicitly:
let b: string;

// Should be an error:
let x;
//  ^? let x: any
```

[Here's a playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUAsEsGdTqAZtAdgUwDSgC4E8AHdBeNJdAJwvQBNkKB7AWwVWh2gEMAbaAL0oAuAFDd0OUJ1ABeUABYATAG5hwkKACC3WA2RosuQsUQFGAN2g1aodAA8CvAMbtueEWIkAjQaFg4KaADmKmpgAMqQDACu3HSexJyoNlQMFO7ioLYq6qAAegD8QA) with that code which has `noImplicitAny` enabled (and `strict`, though I don't think that relates), showing that it doesn't do this check. There is no error on `x`. I can assign any value to it I want, its type is `any`.

Is there a TypeScript config option or combination of options I'm missing?

---

Note: I realize it would be an error for anything to *use* `x` until something is assigned to it. The problem is `x` having the type `any`, leaving it open to have anything assigned to it.

Comment: Surely there is an ESLint rule for this; there's a rule for everything

Comment: @vr. - Oddly, I didn't see one, but also (as I said above) I'd rather not add a linter (like ESLint) to this particular project.

Comment: I think it's impossible, as TS rules are not extendable. And if you need extendable, it'll be linter. So not possible.

Comment: @Dimava - Well, the question is "Is there an option or combination of options I'm missing [to do this]?" -- that is, TypeScript config options. Increasingly I suspect the answer is "no." :-) (At which point, as you say, if one wants it, one needs a linter.) I just find it very surprising, particularly that `noImplicitAny` doesn't cover this. I guess there's a really thin line between "implicit" and "default."

Comment: @zenly https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/init-declarations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to prove a negative, but as far as I can tell looking through the TypeScript options, no, there's no way to have TypeScript (as opposed to a linter) enforce either an initializer or a type on `let` declarations.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing one important thing
Undefined variable is obviously `any`, but at the moment you start to use it it acquires a type

And if it is *actually* used as "implicit any" there *is* a error - you just didn't write a proper test for that

```
function f<T>(x: T){}
let x; // any
//  ^?
//  let x: any

console.log(x)
//          ^?
//          let x: undefined

x = 'blah'
console.log(x)
//          ^?
//          let x: string

f<string>(x) // ok
f<number>(x) // error

x = +x;
console.log(x)
//          ^?
//          let x: number

f<string>(x) // error
f<number>(x) // ok


function g() {
    console.log(x)
    //          ^! TS7005 Variable 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    //          ^?
    //          let x: any
}
```

Comment: *"Undefined variable is obviously any, but at the moment you start to use it it acquires a type"* No, its type is *narrowed* (temporarily) through flow analysis. That is not the same thing as acquiring a type. Its actual type remains `any`, as evidenced by your code above where the narrowed type was `string` after assigning a string to `x`, but then you're allowed to assign a number to it later.

Comment: The point of the question is that I want to prevent `let x;` declarations (that is, `let` without an initializer or a type). It doesn't matter that its apparent type gets narrowed by an assignment (and then narrowed to something else if you assign something else to it), the point is that **it shouldn't be `any` in the first place**, it should have the appropriate type for what we're going to use it for. That's the restriction I'm looking for. And, sadly, which doesn't seem to exist in TypeScript itself.